# Adaptive PayPal payment in iOS

Tags: ios, paypal

Is there any documentation available for adaptive payment of paypal with iOS?

I have got a documentation, but I couldn't find any source code for implementing PayPal parallel payment with iOS. Can anybody help me to get aware of Adaptive payment with iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the paypal sdk for ios found [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index) under mobile payments. The zip file contains the library, sample codes and documentation. Basically, to use parallel payments, you just set multiple receivers of the payment. There is also an example on how to implement simple payment, chained payment and preapproval.

Comment: Has anyone actually launched an iOS app that uses the PP sdk? I can't find a single example.

Comment: Check out Qwiqq - It uses the MPL SDK